# How to find all json attributes?

Tags: json, database, attributes, dataset

Im working on a ml project and im trying to find all the attributes of my data. I have a few json files, and each node in the file has different attributes. Im trying to find a way to get all the attributes from all the nodes in the files. Is there a good way?
Thank you.

Comment: what language you are using .. is it python ??

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume this is the json data present in your file

```
let json_data = {

    "node1":{
        "key1_1":"val1_1",
        "key1_2": "val1_2"
    },
    "node2":{
        "key2_1":"val2_1",
        "key2_2": "val2_2"
    },
    "node3":{
        "key3_1":"val3_1",
        "key3_2": "val3_2"
    },
}
```

Solution in ***python*** will be

```
attrs = [att for node in json_data for att in json_data[node]]
```

Solution in ***JS***  will be

```
// getting all the nodes first 
nodes = Object.keys(json_data);


attrs=[];  // Array to store all the attributes

for(let node in nodes ){

    // getting the attributes of current node.
    curr_attrs= [...Object.keys(json_data[node])];
    attrs.push(...curr_attrs );
}
```

Output for above code is

```
>> attrs
(6) ["key1_1", "key1_2", "key2_1", "key2_2", "key3_1", "key3_2"]
```